# Многопоточный сервер

Tags: база-данных, многопоточность, клиент-сервер, qt, c++

Стоит задача в создании многопоточного сервера для: 
1.обработки и внесения в БД постоянно поступающей информации
2.обработки клиентских запросов к БД

Пишу на С++. Не могу выбрать между библиотеками QT и POCO. Как бы обе подходят для решения данной задачи. Ни с одной из них раньше не работал, так что личной привязанности к ним не имею. Описания к ним покурил - в общем то по сложности осваивания они где то рядом. Интересует ваше мнение - какую лучше библиотеку использовать и почему?

Comment: Вы предполагаете сотни запросов в секунду к серверу ? Если меньше, то не связывайтесь с потоками и общей памятью, делайте несколько процессов. Надежность многократно возрастет.

Answer (score 2):

Говоря конкретно о вашей задаче, функциональность `Qt` и `POCO` полностью идентична друг другу. *Т.е я за пару минут не смог придумать какую-либо подзадачу, которую, например, можно сделать с применением `POCO`, но не с применением `Qt`.*

В таком случае, очевидно, стоит большей частью подумать про процесс *"вливания"* в разработку и, на мой личный взгяд, *(а также ориентируясь на некоторые мнения из веба)*, стоит все-таки сделать выбор в пользу `Qt`.

Однажды разобравшись с `Qt`, вы вполне сможете использовать его для других проектов, включая и `GUI`-приложения **(это то, чего нельзя сделать на `POCO`).** Плюс в нем больше количество примеров готовых приложений, мне лично больше нравится документация, да и `community` разработчиков несомненно больше.

---

Из минусов `Qt`, которые можно придумать - необходимость внедрять `moc-компилятор` в свой `build toolchain`, ну и некоторая неповоротливость с достаточно большим количеством `dll` библиотек. Первая проблема легко решается использованием `Qt Creator` или, например, с помощью плагинов для других `IDE`. Вторая - это, в общем-то, скорее, мое личное мнение, которое идет вразрез со мнением остальных.

---

*Еще по теме можно почитать:*

- [**ACE vs Boost vs Poco vs wxWidgets**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760522/ace-vs-boost-vs-poco-vs-wxwidgets)
- [**Investigating overlap between Qt, boost, POCO**](http://wiki.realxtend.org/index.php/Investigate_the_overlap_between_Qt/Poco/Boost)

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к QT. Тогда сопутствующий вопрос о среде разработки. Я так понимаю QT Creator наиболее подходящая, там и с Qt Designer интеграция идет.  
В общем то потратив сегодня некоторое время я "Hellow world" и на Dev-C++ (MinGW) скомпилировал, и в VisualStudio 2010 проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Изучив обе библиотеки чуть более детально, точнее сказать те части библиотек, которые предназначены для решения поставленной задачи, я пришел к выводу что POCO все же подходит немного лучше, чем QT, просто из-за того, что там уже реализованы классы многопоточного сервера и пула нитей (в QT я этого пока не обнаружил). При асинхронной работе сокетов пул потоков справляется с входящими подключениями очень даже неплохо, да и механизм выбора наименее загруженной нити тоже уже есть. В общем меня устроило.
А вот в QT мне понравился механизм сигнал-слот для организации взаимодействия между потоками, но мне это просто на данный момент не нужно.